# difference between execute shell script directly and through pipe

Tags: shell

my shell script called mongoLogin.sh as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
mongo
use demo
show tables
```

the function of above is logining mongo and show tables of database called demo. 
if I execute it directly by:

```
sh mongoLogin.sh
```

it works. however if I execute it by this way as below:

```
cat mongoLogin.sh | sh
```

compared with execute directly, it will exit automatically, as well as I `ctrl+c` after execute it directly. It seemed the `sh` command after pipe will create a new subprocess, and this subprocess finish due to some reason.
   Do there exist some method that I can achieve same result by execute script through pipe?

**update:**
when execute directly it seemed only the first command make effect, because following commands are mongo operations rather than shell commands. And when I execute it by pipe, all commands make effect, but it exit automatically.

the output of executing it through pipe as below:

```
xxx@xxxMacBook-Pro:~/Downloads$cat mongoLogin.sh | sh
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("43c55950-f9e2-49ca-a458- 
611f8c71eae4") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.3
switched to db demo
test
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Both variants don't work, because `use demo` is not a valid shell command.

I have not worked with mongo, but if the command accepts is input from stdin, you can try

```
mongo <<OGNOM
use demo
show tables
OGNOM
```

Make sure that the final OGNOM starts in the first column of your line!

Comment: it seemed `use demo` make effect when executing script through pipe. I have add the output of it.

Comment: In your example, you are just feeding the lines of your "script" (which should better regarded not as a script, but simply as a set of input lines) to the stdin of `sh`. Once `sh` sees the `mongo` line, it starts mongo, and now all stdin goes to mongo. This means that the `use` line is fed into mongo.

Comment: @ user1934428 Yeah, I agree you much. But now the question is that it will exit automatically which is not what I expect.

Comment: When the input file ends, an EOF is sent, which causes mongo to terminate. What else it mongo supposed to do? If you want to interact with the open session afterwards, you need something like (for instance) [Expect](https://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/tcl-course/topics/expect.html).